# Ways to Turn Electrical Energy into Kinetic Energy?

Tags: energy, energy-harvesting, tesla-coil

We want to build a pumpkin chunkin' launcher from Tesla Coil parts (and maybe some more). We were originally thinking a rail gun would be the closest thing to make it, but from the designs I've seen it would have to be massive to fit a pumpkin.

I also know of electric motors which turn electrical energy to kinetic energy, but I don't see how we could use this could launch a pumpkin.

Are there any other ways to turn Electrical Energy to Kinetic Energy so we can launch a pumpkin?

Could you please let me know how I can make my question more on topic before downvoting?

Comment: Have you done any research? It's recommended before posting questions. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @laptop2d I thought I showed research by stating my ideas (rail gun and electric motors). How else should I research?

Comment: No practical answer is likely to have the *coolness* factor of tesla-coils/rail-guns. Probably any practical answer is going to start with "use a motor to (do X) so that it stores energy in (Y system)".

Comment: I would start by googling electrical to kinetic energy, from there I see a wiki page. In the page I see that motors can convert energy, so I start looking at motor types and notice that there are linear motors.

Comment: If you had actually done any real research you'd know you can't really make a rail gun from Tesla coil parts

Comment: @brhans that would be ok. I'm just interested to see what people think would be the best implementation. We already have a Tesla coil built, and just thought rail guns were related. I thought rail gun would be a good idea because it can reach Mach speeds easily

Comment: @DerStrom8 I disagree. Rail guns require high voltage and high amperage which tesla coils provide?

Comment: Rail guns and Tesla coils are not related at all (other than the fact that they're both electrical devices that rely on magnetic fields).

Comment: @SethKitchen No, rail guns require high voltage, high current DC. Tesla coils provide high voltage, low current, high frequency Alternating current. They are not related.

Comment: If you had done any research on launching a pumpkin, you would know that the real issue is not having the pumpkin explode by launching it too fast.

Comment: How else? How to make either of those "ideas" practical. What do they imply in kinetic energy for the pumpkin, what THAT implies for electrical energy - voltages and currents - and what those imply for actually building something. If all you can do is name those "ideas" you haven't STARTED the research. Specs of waht you have won't help - a comparison between those specs and what you need will.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I will add specs of our tesla coils and relevant equations. Would that help?

Comment: @SethKitchen For the last time, Tesla Coils and Rail Guns are not interchangeable. You can't really make one from another. The Theories of operation and the general concepts are entirely different. DO YOUR RESEARCH!

Comment: "specs of our tesla coils" - not really, because DerStrom8 is correct. Tesla coils & rail guns don't have much in common.

Comment: This is simply a list request. There's no question to be answered.

Comment: I will do more research and update my question. Thanks for the jumping off point

Comment: @DerStrom8 can't diode fix AC to DC?

Comment: @SethKitchen Find a diode that can handle half a million volts or more at 100kHz (depending on the Tesla coil) and maybe, but even if you happened to find some magical diode that could do it, you still don't have the current. My suggestion to you would be to just drop it. You clearly don't know what you're doing and you shouldn't even be thinking about playing with high power electronics. Don't be an idiot. Just stop.

Comment: Pull back a spring with a screw thread or other rotary to linear converter. Takes a lot of energy. Car springs or torsion bars may work. Lethal. Wind up a Trebuchet with a winch. That has lots of cool factor. Pump water into a tank in a Trebuchet to make load. Cool!!!!!!. | Compress air. Oh yes!. | 1 kg to 100metres straight up no air needs mgh ~= 1 x 10 x 100 = 1000 J = 1000 Watt seconds. | V = sqrt(2.a.h) = sqrt (2 x 10 x 100) = 45 m/s = 100 mph. Stand clear. Air adds to this. About 120N / 12 kg drag forces at exit for moderate pumpkin. So "rather more" than 100 mph for 100m high.

Comment: Watch an Olympic shot putter. Two styles. Some rotate to gain energy then release. Spin pumpkin on rotary platform accelerating. When appropriate, release, Getting it right could be dangerous (or fatal) and messy and fun.

Comment: Car springs or torsion bars or rubber or .... effectively make a cross-bow. Feasible. Motor turns threaded rod to wind it back. Or use a winch (eg 12V ones available for light car hauling duties) to load energy storing spring. Be aware that death happens. Air cannon as per circu cannon. 12V pump. Slow. Would work. All are potentially lethal.

Answer (score 2):

Use an electric motor to power a compressor to make an air cannon.